# How to list out file names from dropbox in PHP

Tags: php, api, dropbox

I have checked the docs of Dropbox API which had the following code:

```
curl -X POST https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/list_folder \
    --header "Authorization: Bearer " \
    --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
    --data "{\"path\": \"/Homework/math\",\"recursive\": false,\"include_media_info\": false,\"include_deleted\": false,\"include_has_explicit_shared_members\": false,\"include_mounted_folders\": true,\"include_non_downloadable_files\": true}"
```

But how am I to use this code in PHP. I know how to use the header thing. Its like this

```
$headers = array(
    'Authorization: Bearer <ACCESS_TOKEN>',
    'Content-Type: application/json')
```

But how to use the data part. When i input it like "Data" : ..... , then it gives me this error " Error in call to API function "files/list_folder": request body: could not decode input as JSON". What should I do?

Comment: `--data` specifies the body of POST request

Comment: I redacted it from your post, but note that access tokens enable access to Dropbox accounts, so for the sake of security, you should never share access tokens like this. Since this access token has been shared here, you should disable this access token. You can do so by revoking access to the app entirely, if the access token is for your account, here:

https://www.dropbox.com/account/connected_apps

Or, you can disable just this access token using the API:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#auth-token-revoke

Comment: Note that doing so will cause any further API calls made using this access token to fail. This cannot be undone, and you would need to get a new access token to replace this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/list_folder');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\"path\": \"/Homework/math\",\"recursive\": false,\"include_media_info\": false,\"include_deleted\": false,\"include_has_explicit_shared_members\": false,\"include_mounted_folders\": true,\"include_non_downloadable_files\": true}");

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Authorization: Bearer';
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
```